# Calling Javascript function from a C++ callback in V8

Tags: c++, multithreading, v8, libuv

I'm trying to call a registered JS function when a c++ callback is called, but I'm getting a segfault for what I assume is a scoping issue.

```
 Handle<Value> addEventListener( const Arguments& args ) {
    HandleScope scope;
    if (!args[0]->IsFunction()) {
        return ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(String::New("Wrong arguments")));
    }

    Persistent<Function> fn = Persistent<Function>::New(Handle<Function>::Cast(args[0]));
    Local<Number> num = Number::New(registerListener(&callback, &fn));
    scope.Close(num);
}
```

When an event happens, the following method is called. I'm assuming that this probably happens on another thread to which V8 is executing JS.

```
void callback(int event, void* context ) {
    HandleScope scope;
    Local<Value> args[] = { Local<Value>::New(Number::New(event)) };
    Persistent<Function> *func = static_cast<Persistent<Function> *>(context);
    (* func)->Call((* func), 1, args);

    scope.Close(Undefined());
}
```

This causes a Segmentation fault: 11. Note that if I call the callback function directly with a reference to Persistent from addEventListener(), it executes the function correctly.

I'm assuming that I need a Locker or Isolate? It also looks like libuv's uv_queue_work() might be able to solve this, but since I don't start the thread, I can't see how you would use it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you declare `Persistent<Function> fn` in your code, `fn` is a stack-allocated variable.

`fn` is a `Persistent<Function>`, which is a *handle* class, and it will contain a pointer to some heap-allocated value of type `Function`, but `fn` itself is on the stack.

This means that when you call `registerListener(&callback, &fn)`, `&fn` is taking the address of the handle (type `Persistent<Function>`), not the address of the `Function` on the heap. When your function exits, the handle will be destroyed but the `Function` itself will remain on the heap.

So as a fix, I suggest passing the address of the `Function` instead of the address of the handle, like this:

```
Persistent<Function> fn = Persistent<Function>::New(Handle<Function>::Cast(args[0]));
Local<Number> num = Number::New(registerListener(&callback, *fn));
```

(note that `operator*` on a `Persistent<T>` returns a `T*` rather than the more conventional `T&`, c.f. http://bespin.cz/~ondras/html/classv8_1_1Handle.html)

You'll also have to adjust `callback` to account for the fact that `context` is now a raw pointer to a `Function`, like this:

```
Persistent<Function> func = static_cast<Function*>(context);
func->Call((* func), 1, args);
```

Creating a `Persistent<Function>` from a raw Function pointer here is OK because we know that `context` is actually a persistent object.

I've also changed `(*func)->Call(...)` to `func->Call(...)` for brevity; they do the same thing for V8 handles.

Comment: Thanks, this does simplify the code and fixes the scoping issue, but I was hoping for some information as to how to call back to the main thread from the callback thread. I have achieved this using eio_nop() function from the EIO library, but the preferred way is to use libuv. My problem is that there doesn't seem to be a libuv equivilent of eio_nop.

Comment: @marchaos Ok. I wasn't entirely clear what you were after on the threading side. As I understand it, what you're after is being able to execute JS from the callback in the main v8 thread's context. I've put together a small demo of how to do this with isolates/lockers (https://gist.github.com/4341994). Note that this'll mean you have to adjust everywhere you use V8 to lock the isolate before doing anything else!

Comment: Thanks. Will give this a go , but looks like the right approach.

Answer (score 14):

I know this question is a bit old, but there has been a pretty major update in nodejs v0.10 to v0.12. V8 changed the behavior of v8::Persistent. v8::Persistent no longer inherits from v8::Handle. I was updating some code and found that the following worked...

```
  void resize(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &args) {
    Isolate *isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    HandleScope scope(isolate);
    Persistent<Function> callback;
    callback.Reset(isolate, args[0].As<Function>())
    const unsigned argc = 2;
    Local<Value> argv[argc] = { Null(isolate), String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "success") };
    Local<Function>::New(isolate, work->callback)->Call(isolate->GetCurrentContext()->Global(), argc, argv);
    callback.Reset();
  }
```

I believe the goal of this update was to make it harder to expose memory leaks. In node v0.10, you would have done something like the following...

```
  v8::Local<v8::Value> value = /* ... */;
  v8::Persistent<v8::Value> persistent = v8::Persistent<v8::Value>::New(value);
  // ...
  v8::Local<v8::Value> value_again = *persistent;
  // ...
  persistent.Dispose();
  persistent.Clear();
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in addEventListener, `Persistent<Function> fn` is allocated on the stack, and then you're taking the pointer to that to use as a context for the callback.

But, because `fn` is allocated on the stack, it disappears when `addEventListener` exits. So withing the callback `context` now point to some bogus value.

You should allocate some heap space, and put all the data you need in `callback` there.

Comment: I believe internally V8 allocations anything Persistent to the heap - it's certainly designed to be there until you explicitly dispose of it.

Comment: confirm. "Persistent handles provide a reference to a heap-allocated JavaScript Object" from https://developers.google.com/v8/embed