# Can't access V8 Context in "callback" function

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, embedded-v8

I am writing a NodeJS addon where I use a C library that lets you register a callback at certain events. When the callback is fired I want to call a NodeJS callback function. The problem is that in my C callback function I get a segmentation fault when trying to do anything V8 related, like creating a HandleScope.

In test.js:

```
...

myaddon.register(function(data) {
  console.log("data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
});

...
```

In test.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <node.h>
#include <v8.h>

using namespace v8;

void WINAPI myEvent(int num, void * context) {
  HandleScope scope; // Segmentation fault here!

  Local<Function> * cb = (Local<Function>*)(context);

  Local<Object> obj = Object::New();
  obj->Set(String::NewSymbol("id"), Number::New(num));

  const int argc = 1;
  Local<Value> argv[argc] = { obj };
  (*cb)->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), argc, argv);

  sleep(1);
}

Handle<Value> RegisterEvent(const Arguments& args) {
    HandleScope scope;

    Local<Function> cb = Local<Function>::Cast(args[0]);

    int callbackId  = registerEvent((Event)&myEvent, &cb );
    printf("callback id: %i\n", callbackId);

    init();

    return scope.Close(Integer::New(callbackId));
}

void init(Handle<Object> exports) {
  exports->Set(String::NewSymbol("register"),
      FunctionTemplate::New(RegisterEvent)->GetFunction());
}

NODE_MODULE(test, init)
```

EDIT: Updated with real code.

EDIT: I just changed the title of this issue since the problem is probably that my callback function can't access the V8 Context. Since I get a segmentation fault when creating HandleScope instance I can't see what else it might be. In addition to this question I AM trying to find the answer in the V8 documentation, but it is huge and I don't have that much time to test and investigate.

Comment: If you're programming an extension for node.js then you're programming in C++ and not C.

Comment: Yes, well, yeah... that is so true. Haven't done anything in either C++ or C for some years now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handler function `myEvent()` must be called in V8 thread. If not, you have to post the event notification into the V8 thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15701160/1355844

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22946062/1355844

Comment: Your answer together with this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826803/calling-javascript-function-from-a-c-callback-in-v8

solved my issue. Now it works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you might have forgotten to create a `HandleScope` for your variable. This should work for you.

```
void callbackFunc() {
  HandleScope scope;
  Local<Object> obj = Object::New();
}
```

Comment: Tried to add HandleScope at the beginning of my callback function, and now I get the SegmentationFault at HandleScope instead. So I think we are getting closer :) Might this be a V8 thing, since the callback is executing whenever depending on when the C library (3rd party) gets an event do I have to rely on V8 features only or might be that V8 is not declared in that scope for some reason?