# how to convert node-addon Persistent<function> to Local<function>?

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, embedded-v8, node.js-addon

I'm trying to update a node.js addon using the old v8 API.

Here is my `wrapper.cpp` code:

```
std::map<int, Persistent<Function> > WrapMdUser::callback_map;

void WrapMdUser::FunCallback(CbRtnField *data) {
std::map<int, Persistent<Function> >::iterator cIt = callback_map.find(data->eFlag);
Local<Number> argv[1] = Nan::New(data->nReason);
cIt->second->Call(Nan::GetCurrentContext()->Global(), 1, argv);
}
```

If I understand it correctly, the author is using a map of `Persistent<function>` to store callbacks in it (see `callback_map` std), but when `node-gyp build`, the compiler throw this error:

```
wrapper.cpp:331:19: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘v8::Persistent<v8::Function>’
cIt->second->Call(Nan::GetCurrentContext()->Global(), 1, argv);
```

What is the best way to update this code to new v8 API so I can run it with last node version?

many thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure this issue is covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826803/calling-javascript-function-from-a-c-callback-in-v8/28554065#28554065

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in this [article](http://blog.scottfrees.com/c-processing-from-node-js-part-4-asynchronous-addons#comment-2728737416), the persistent needs to be converted to a local function first:

```
Local<Function>::New(isolate, work->callback)->
Call(isolate->GetCurrentContext()->Global(), 1, argv);
```

Thanks to @Scott Frees.